# Simulating a long press of mouse left button in JS with testing-library

Tags: javascript, integration-testing, mouse, testing-library

I am writing an integration test and I need to click on an html object for longer than 0.5s.
In the same test I have been able to use `userEvent` to handle various keys' actions, like:

```
  const user = userEvent.setup();
  await user.keyboard("[ShiftLeft>]"); // Press Shift (without releasing it)
  const pointer = await screen.findByText(objectName);
  await user.click(pointer);
  await user.keyboard("[/ShiftLeft]"); // Release Shift
```

I am wondering if there is a way of doing something similar (with or without userEvent) to perform a long click on an object in the page.
Something like:

- mouse left click on X without releasing button
- wait 1s
- release mouse left button

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution to my problem, maybe it can be useful for others :)
It uses the `userEvent` `pointer` from testing-library/user-event.

```
export async function longPress(target: string) {
  const myTarget = await screen.findByText(target);
  const user = userEvent.setup();
  await user.pointer({
    keys: "[MouseLeft>]",
    target: myTarget ,
  });
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  });
  await user.pointer({ keys: "[/MouseLeft]", target: myTarget });
}
```